# Applescript/Automation in Outlook 2016 for Mac

Tags: automation, macros, applescript, microsoft-outlook-2016

Im trying to script some automation for some repetitive tasks I do in my workflow. My script (as of now) needs to accomplish only a basic task, but nonetheless, timesaving. I need it to (when called from another global macro) bring up the "Attach a file" box so that i can choose which file to attach (the file itself is different every time). Here is what I have:

```
tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
     set theAttachment to choose file
     make new attachment with properties {file name:theAttachment}
end tell
```

I'm getting a syntax error: Expected expression, etc. but found “:”.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: also, at this point, i will keep only the attachment portion of my automation in apple script. The rest I'd rather manage and create in Keyboard Maestro.

Comment: I don't have Outlook so I can't test it but in Mail it'd be something more like ` tell msg to make new attachment with properties {file name:theAttachment as alias}
`

Comment: I still get the syntax error in apple script.

Comment: tell application "Mail"
 set theAttachmentFile to choose file
 set msg to make new outgoing message with properties {visible:true}
 tell msg to make new attachment with properties {file name:theAttachmentFile as alias}
 end tell

Answer (score 2):

There is no "file name" property for attachments in Outlook. You are referencing a file, not a filename.

You also need to state what you want to do with the attachment (attach it to a message).

```
tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
    set theMessage to make new outgoing message
    set theAttachment to choose file
    make new attachment at the end of theMessage with properties {file:theAttachment}
    open theMessage
end tell
```

Answer (score -1):

```
tell current messages
     make new attachment with properties {file:theAttachment}
end tell
```

Comment: Please explain what this does or why this is the correct solution.